# переинициализация usb программно в Windows

Tags: usb

Нужна такая утилита, которая бы действовала на USB устройство подобно его переподключению к компьютеру. Требуется такая обработка в среде Windows. Какие можно использовать механизмы для реализации такой утилиты? Принимаются к рассмотрению утилиты в средах unix, Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [devcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx) с параметрами restart *DEV_ID*

Device ID можно получить в диспетчере устройств Сведениях, id оборудования.

Comment: команда `devcon.exe restart USB*` отработала перезапуск всех USB, но потребовала для некоторых из них перезагрузку, а одно и вовсе не удалось перезапустить;  [скриншот](https://yadi.sk/i/-kzfFRrcfrgsq)